# PHP условия для регистрационной формы

Tags: php

Это часть кода условий для заполнения формы.
 У меня (у чайника) 2 вопроса:
1) Данный код позволяет для заполнения логина ввести пробел, а я хочу запретить пробели в логине, как это реализовать? 
2) Если логин написали правильный, но потом ошибка в пароле, у меня выводит ошибку, но при этом логин приходиться снова написать... можно же как-то сохранить правильно заполненный логин в таком случае?

```
// login
else if (iconv_strlen($login) < 1){
        $_SESSION['error']['login'] = "Please, write login!";
    } else if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$/', $login)) {
        $_SESSION['error']['login'] = 'Name can only contain letters and numbers';
}
// password
else if (iconv_strlen($password) < 1){
        $_SESSION['error']['password'] = "Please, write password!";
    } else if (iconv_strlen($password) != iconv_strlen($password_confirm)){
        $_SESSION['error']['password_confirm'] = "Those passwords didn't match!";
        } else {
            $password = md5($password);
            $connect->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`full_name`, `login`, `email`, `password`, `avatar`) VALUES ('$full_name', '$login', '$email', '$password', '$avatar')");
        }
```

Comment: Впервые вижу пароль из одной буквы)) Но это исправимо, не обращайте внимания))

Comment: Зачем внесли пробельный символ в регулярное выражение? Зачем проверяете длину строки, если можно в регулярке задать минимальную и максимальную длину символов? Вопросов больше, чем ответов, но всё равно спасибо, хоть посмеялся чуть-чуть

Comment: Посмеяться над новичками - это круто, конечно, не спорю, но если бы подсказали какой символ именно отвечает за пробел и как задать нужную длину -было бы круче.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы запретить ввод пробелов через регулярное выражение - Вам необходимо удалить `\s` из него. 
Чтобы задать количество символов в строке, Вы можете использовать `{От скольки, до скольки}`.
Пример (Ограничение по количеству символов в 10):

```php
else if (iconv_strlen($login) < 1){
        $_SESSION['error']['login'] = "Please, write login!";
    } else if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,10}+$/', $login)) {
        $_SESSION['error']['login'] = 'Name can only contain letters and numbers';
}
// password
else if (iconv_strlen($password) < 1){
        $_SESSION['error']['password'] = "Please, write password!";
    } else if (iconv_strlen($password) != iconv_strlen($password_confirm)){
        $_SESSION['error']['password_confirm'] = "Those passwords didn't match!";
        } else {
            $password = md5($password);
            $connect->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`full_name`, `login`, `email`, `password`, `avatar`) VALUES ('$full_name', '$login', '$email', '$password', '$avatar')");
        }
```

Чтобы сохранить логин введённым, Вы можете либо передать значение в файл `php` с формой, и выводить его примерно так:

```php
<input <?php if($login){ echo 'value: "'.$login.'"'?>>
```

В данном случае, мы проверяем наличие значения в переменной `$login`, и если оно присутствует, то добавляем его в `value` поля `input`.

Или же после передачи данных в основной файл `php` можно проставлять значение через `js`.

Или же использовать `localstorage` или `cookie` для добавления значения в поле ввода через `javascript` или `php`.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все доходчиво написали! Супер!!!

Comment: @Ерванд С-ян Рад помочь. Удачи Вам в Вашем проекте. ) Если будут вопросы - смело обращайтесь, Вам обязательно тут помогут.